# if statment : "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

Hello I have this code:

```
array = 0
with open('items.txt') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    abre_arquivo1 = open("dict.txt","w") 
    for p in data['data']:
        abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['order_id'])+ "\','")
        abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['pedido_venda'])+ "\','") 
        abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['supplier_id'])+ "\','") 
        abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['created_at'])+ "\','") 
        abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['data_retorno_nf'])+ '\n')
        for item in p:
            abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][array]['item'])+ "\','")
            abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][array]['mm_product_id'])+ "\','")
            abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][array]['mm_product_id'])+ "\','")
            abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][array]['description'])+ "\','")
            array += 1         
            if array >= int(p['items'][array]['item']):
                array = 0
            else:
                print(array)
                next
```

When I try to execute it, this error shows up **"list index out of range"** on the `If` statement, instead of changing the value for `array = 0`.
What I'm doing wrong here?

Inside the `items.txt` file is a json:

```
{"data":[{"order_id":74415,"pedido_venda":"Z92211","supplier_id":1042,"status":9,"priority":null,"created_at":"2014-09-22 00:00:00","approved_at":"2014-09-19 00:00:00","assistence":0,"items":[{"item":"0002","mm_product_id":"98610","sku":"BA1068 BR","description":"Bau Art in Moveis BA1068 BR Branco                      ","quantity":1,"unity":"UN","price_unity":72.86,"price_total":72.86,"cst":null},{"item":"0003","mm_product_id":"98616","sku":"BL1030FR","description":"Balcao para Forno Microondas Art in Moveis BL1030 FR Fresno ","quantity":1,"unity":"UN","price_unity":86.11,"price_total":86.11,"cst":null},{"item":"0004","mm_product_id":"98629","sku":"AR4000 BR","description":"Armario para lavanderia Art in Moveis AR4000 BR Branco   ","quantity":1,"unity":"UN","price_unity":146.28,"price_total":146.28,"cst":null}],"data_retorno_nf":"2014-10-10","data_estimada_entrega_cd":"2014-10-15
00:00:00","prazo_para_faturamento":"2014-10-10","filial":[],"cliente":[{"bairro":" Jardim S\u00e3o Paulo(Zona Norte)","cep":"02040090","cidade":"S\u00e3o Paulo","cpfcnpj":"13549318820","email":"1042_artin@sandbox","endereco":"R Ag Gomes, 258, apto.92","ibge":"00000","ibgecompleto":"3500000","incricaoestadual":"ISENTO","nome":"SILVANA ANGELICA LOPES","telefone":"11- 36760352","tipocli":"F","tipocontrib":"F","uf":"SP"}],"transportadora":[]}
```

Comment: Clearly `array` is at least as big as the size of `p['items']`; without knowing what is in your file, can't say much else.

Comment: they file is empty it will get the json for the `('items.txt')` file. The problem is when i take the `abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][array]['item'])+ "\','")` and change to `abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][0]['item'])+ "\','")` then`abre_arquivo1.write(str(p['items'][1]['item'])+ "\','")`. it works fine. the problem is when `(p['items'][array]['item'])` is bigger then the array because it doesn't execute the if statment,just shows the error.

Comment: It shows the error because it is *trying* to execute the if statement and failing.  And I was talking about what is in `items.txt`.

Comment: I have added what is inside the `items.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `array` loop index variable here. Just loop over the list directly with `for item in p['items']:`.

This will simplify such code significantly, since you don't have to write all that bug-prone `array += 1` code.

```
data = json.load('items.txt')['data']
with open('dict.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for p in data:
        fp.write("'{order_id}', '{pedido_venta}', '{supplier_id}'".format(**p))
        for item in p['items']:
            fp.write('{item}', '{mm_product_id}', '{description}'".format(**item))
```

Adjust the format strings as needed to get the intended output.

Note that your original `for item in p:` would loop over every key in the object `p`, instead of looping over the items in the list `p['items']`.

Comment: Thx @HåkenLid for the help. It worked the way i wanted.